# How do LED light fixtures accomplish multi-spectral (switch-selectable) color temperature capability?

Tags: light-fixture, led

This is more of a technology question perhaps - I was wondering how the LED light fixtures that feature switchable color temperature work.  Do they contain multiple sets of LED's that emit different color temperatures, or are there now LED's that can alter their color temperature based on some input or control signal?

Comment: How is this related to home improvement? There are several different technology’s try googling and reading up on the types.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because has nothing to do with home improvement.

Answer (score 2):

That is correct.  They contain both cool white and warm white elements, and they  dim/blend between them.  You only really need two color temps - 2700k and 5500k - to cover the gamut with dimming/blending.